# How can I add opencv libraries to setup.py?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, distutils, setup.py

I have created an embedded Python code where a C++ function is called from Python. I have created the setup.py as following.

```
from distutils.core import setup,Extension

extension_mod=Extension('getGender',['getGender.cpp'],library_dirs=['/usr/local/include/opencv2/contrib','/usr/local/include/opencv2/core','/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui','/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc','/usr/local/include'])

setup(name='getGender',ext_modules=[extension_mod])
```

But I am getting this error.

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/getGender.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
```

How can I reference these opencv libraries in my setup.py? Please advice.

Comment: This works in my case and it may be one solution to such problems.[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423512/calling-c-code-from-python-using-cython-whith-the-distutilis-approach)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by going to `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig` and modifying your `opencv.pc` to explicitly have all libraries. You may also have move the plugins from `/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.xx` to `/usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.xx`

Comment: I don't have a lib64 folder. There is a lib folder in usr, inside that there is no opencv.pc Please help

Comment: Opencv.pc is there in usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. What should I do there?

Answer (score 0):

try

libraries=['opencv_core'],